# How do i get my comment box in html to send information into another file and not php

Tags: html

Im trying to get my html comment box to work how i want it. When it is filled out. I want the information to be sent to a .txt file or .json file or something compact and easy to read. Anyone have and code suggestions because im having so much trouble.
TIP: i dont know php and how it works and ive tried it. It dont work for me. The file cant read it.

Comment: How can we suggest you code unless you din try your own.? Please do try your own and paste your code also here so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you will need to change some of the statements to suit your needs... but try this...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
function WriteToSomeFile()
{
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\NewFile.txt", true);
var text=document.getElementById("TextArea1").innerText;
s.WriteLine(text);
s.WriteLine('***********************');
s.Close();
}
</script>

<form name="SaveToFile">
<textarea name="text">EXAMPLE</textarea>
<button onclick="WriteToSomeFile()">Click here to save</Button>  
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you i will try changing my statements.